# Can I end my question with a preposition in this case?

Tags: prepositions, word-order

May I say the following sentence, which ends with the preposition *in* (the same as happen as with *from*).

> What does Insulin play role **in**?

Comment: The "in" is not necessary if you structure the question as follows: "What role does insulin play (in regulating glucose levels)?"

Comment: Thank you. Actually I know many ways to ask this question, but I would like to know if this way particularly is grammatically correct.

Comment: _What does Insulin play role in?_ is not meaningful in English. If it's supposed to be _What role does Insulin play in?_ then _in_ lacks an object. What are you trying to express here, exactly?

Comment: Did you miss the indefinite article before *role*?  A question like "What [biological processes] does Insulin play a role in?" sounds okay to me.

Comment: I am just trying to ask a question in such way and to know if it's correct. according to what I read in your comments, then I can conclude that this is not correct and it should be one of the two following options: a) What role does Insulin play in our body?, or, b) what role in our body does insulin play in? Am I right?   For one thing I am sure - I saw in the many times in English a construction of questions which end with the preposition "in" - in questions. I don't know if it's correct or not but I saw it many times and would like to understand or to know something about its correctness.

Comment: Did you intended to write **a role in** in your original question? As @cbh notes, _What does insulin play (a) role **in**?_ is perfectly proper. Is that what you're trying ask? _What organ does insulin come **from**?_ and _What does the body use insulin **for**?_ and _What organ is insulin produced **in**?_ are all fine, too. There are many ways to end a question with a preposition.

Comment: "What role in our body does insulin play in" is grammatically incorrect, because the second preposition **in** has no object. _"What role in our body does insulin play?"_ and _"What role does insulin play in our body?"_ are both correct. There isn't a way to phrase this particular question so that it ends with **in**, though.

Comment: If you want an example of a sentence which ends with *in*, here's one. ""What film/movie did you appear/star in?"

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule against ending a sentence with a preposition. That "style point" was made up by people hundreds of years ago who thought English should follow the rules of Latin.

You could say either:

> What does insulin play a role in.

or better

> What process does insulin play a role in.

or turn it around and say

> What role does insulin play in [the process].

See [When is it appropriate to end a sentence with a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition) for more information.

Comment: Valiant and clear, but I'm still not sure that this is the gist of his question, because he or she deigns to enlighten us.

Comment: Great, because I was just going for clear.